# android how to drag a hidden view/fragment from the screen left side inside my app

Tags: android, custom-view

how to implement a hidden view  only part shown is used to drag it from the side, as follow:-

[image]

[image]

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Try using standard Google libraries like [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) or [ViewDragHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper.html).

As it seems you're trying to replicate the exact same pattern / behaviour.